# Multiple conditional selection criteria in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Probably a simple one:

I have a `data.frame` such as this:

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(name=c("A","A","B","C","B","A"),id=1:6,rep1=rnorm(6),rep2=rnorm(6),rep3=rnorm(6))
```

In the `UI` part of the `R` `shiny` `server` I'd like to have a drop-down menu that lists `unique(df$name)`, and then given that selection, in a second drop-down menu I'd like to list all `df$id` that correspond to that `df$name` selection (i.e., if the selected name is `selected.name`, this will be: `dplyr::filter(df,name == selected.name)$id`). Then given these two selections (which are a unique row in `df`) I'd like to execute `server`, which executes this function to plot the given selection:

```
plotData <- function(selected.df)
{
  plot.df <- reshape2::melt(dplyr::select(selected.df,-name,-id))
  ggplot2::ggplot(plot.df,ggplot2::aes(x=variable,y=value))+ggplot2::geom_point()+ggplot2::theme_minimal()
}
```

Here's the `shiny` `code` I'm trying:

```
server <- function(input, output)
{
  output$id <- renderUI({
    selectInput("id", "ID", choices = unique(dplyr::filter(df,name == input$name)$id))
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plotData(selected.df=dplyr::filter(df,name == input$name,id == output$id))
  })
}


ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Results Explorer"),

  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # select name
      selectInput("name", "Name", choices = unique(df$name)),
      uiOutput("id")
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)
```

When I run: `shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`, I get the error:

```
Evaluation error: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed..
```

What's missing?

Comment: start here https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

Answer (score 1):

Here the option would be have `renderUI` in the 'server' and `uiOuput` in 'ui'

-ui

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Results Explorer"),

  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # select name


      selectInput("name", "Name", choices = unique(df$name)),

      uiOutput("idselection")



      # select id - this is where I need help


    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      # ShinyServer part
      plotOutput("plot")

    )
  )
)
```

-server

```
server = function(input, output) {

  output$idselection <- renderUI({
      selectInput("id", "ID", choices = unique(df$id[df$name ==input$name]))
  }) 

 output$plot <- renderPlot({

   df %>%
      count(name) %>%
      ggplot(., aes(x = name, y = n, fill = name)) +
           geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
           theme_bw()


 })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun. I updated my question to fit your answer since I'm still getting an error. Any idea what's missing?

Comment: @dan Looks like you answered it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, tiny fix:

Create data:
    set.seed(1)

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("A","A","B","C","B","A"),id=1:6,rep1=rnorm(6),rep2=rnorm(6),rep3=rnorm(6))
```

Function that server will execute:

```
plotData <- function(selected.df)
{
  plot.df <- reshape2::melt(dplyr::select(selected.df,-name,-id))
  ggplot2::ggplot(plot.df,ggplot2::aes(x=variable,y=value))+ggplot2::geom_point()+ggplot2::theme_minimal()
}
```

`shiny` `code`:

```
server <- function(input, output)
{
  output$id <- renderUI({
    selectInput("id", "ID", choices = unique(dplyr::filter(df,name == input$name)$id))
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plotData(selected.df=dplyr::filter(df,name == input$name,id == input$id))
  })
}


ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Results Explorer"),

  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # select name
      selectInput("name", "Name", choices = unique(df$name)),
      uiOutput("id")
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)
```